# Is there any way to remotly access ios device from another ios device?

Tags: ios, appletv

I have Ipod touch which is connected to TV. Is there any app that allow this Ipod be controlled remotely using another IOS device like Ipad? (for sure without jail breaking)

Or more specifically, Is there any apps available that convert ipod touch into virtual apple tv?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible due to restrictions in place on iOS (namely sandboxing and multitasking).

Answer (score 1):

Without a jailbreak? Absolutely not. With a jailbreak? Sure, install `veency` from Saurik's repository, Telesphoreo Tangelo, in Cydia on the host device, and then install a VNC app from the App Store on the client device.